# Webpack 4 splitChunks and dynamic imports: only deploy new/updated modules?

Tags: webpack

I've been working on improving client caching by generating multiple bundles. I've set things up so there's 1 entry.js shared among all pages of my site, and page-specific modules are conditionally dynamically imported at runtime. My Webpack uses both splitChunks bundles and bundles that are auto-generated via Webpack's dynamic import with magic comment feature. The issue I'm encountering is that when I build, if I deploy only new/modified bundles along with entry.js then everything fails. Can I somehow configure Webpack to internally keep its bundle references the same across builds, so that I'm able to only deploy new/modified bundles?

Comment: Starting to think that hot module replacement (HMR) is the answer ...

Comment: Looks like HMR is mostly a dev tool vs prod. I added chunkFilename: "[name]/[name].bundle.js" to my webpack.config output but no dice ... deploying only new/modified bundles still breaks

Comment: Starting to think an optimization setting or settings could get things working ...

Answer (score 0):

So I found that I needed to set 2 configs in webpack.config:

```
configuration.moduleIds: "named",
configuration.chunkIds: "named",
```

I'm going to do more tests but for now I can deploy a new bundle and modified bundles without needing to deploy all of the bundles generated by a build.